# Questions about player behavior in Online Games

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

In Online games the behavior of other players is a really important thing. Especially when it comes to competitive games or MMOs. Basically every game you aren't just in a small group (Coop zombie modus in COD for example) but where there are a large amount of other players you can play with/compete against (WoW/League of legends as an example).

Now of course. Player behavior is a sensitive topic  to talk about since not every player is the same, but what I've learned from LoL and WoW are that a lot of things can be seen in a majority of players.

A gamer that plays a lot of Online games will often know how a majority of the community in the game reacts both in terms of playing behavior and often also with interpersonal behavior.

As I said above, the two "behaviors" would be (With example questions):

**Interpersonal Behavior**

- How can I prevent people from raging at eachother in a bad Game (League of Legends).
- What things increase my chance of getting invite for a Raid/Guild in (World of Warcraft)

**In-Game Behavior**

- What are the most common used ways to dodge spells (DotA2)
- Where will most campers hide on Crash (CoDMW4)

Now yes these questinos might seem very subjective just from the titles, but if you actively play one of these games you just know these things. There are certain partterns in the behavior of players and while answers to these questions may not work for individual problems, they will work for the "majority" that's being asked about. So are these questions allowed or not?

Comment: Good subjective questions are allowed on Arqade. This would include these questions

Comment: I'd say the In-Game behaviour questions are fine.  The interpersonal, I would vote against.  While yes, those are things gamers will deal with on occasion, I feel it doesn't play to our strengths.

Comment: I believe that even the interpersonal questions, *if* properly worded, can be answered in objective terms.

Comment: To be honest, those questions sound better than something like "Where are the teddy bears in CoD:MW2".  Both require a user that has spent a bit of time with the game.  The difference is that a non-user can find teddy bear locations on the [CoD Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Teddy_Bear), while the other requires much more research.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion, it's relatively easy to distinguish a "Good" subjective question from a "Bad" subjective question. A "Good" Subjective question can be answered with a perfectly good answer by someone who, as you say, has an advanced technical knowledge of the game and the players of the said game. Yes the answer might include some subjectivity but an experienced player should be able to back up his answer with example, and give a more general point of view than only his opinion.

*What are the most common used ways to dodge spells (DotA2) ?* and *What is the best spell to use as an escape in DotA 2 ?* are completely different. The second one would probably be closed as primarily opinion based while the first (that you suggested) is the kind of question that an experienced DotA player will be able to answer without any degree of subjectivity. If you play the game, you know what spells are used, why they are used, in what situation they shine or are useless etc. This kind of answer are really good and often explain a lot to the asker. If you can mix knowledge with experience in the answer, *Good* subjective question simply turns into *Good* questions that will help most people reading it.

Some times ago I answered a question about [the best way to spend paragon point as a Demon Hunter in Diablo 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159658/as-a-demon-hunter-what-bonuses-should-i-focus-on-when-spending-paragon-points/159722#159722). and as Stated by [Frank](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159658/as-a-demon-hunter-what-bonuses-should-i-focus-on-when-spending-paragon-points/159722#comment213966_159658) :

> To close voters: This is exactly the type of question that we can get
>   good subjective answers on. Yes, it will require some degree of
>   subjectivity. Any answers should back up their opinions with why they
>   have chosen the build they have. These types of questions are the
>   bread and butter of Arqade.

Which I totally agree with. You can take a look at the question and my answer and you will understand that a subjective question is not necessarily a bad question. *[More on the topic right here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)*

I also think that the choice of word matters a lot when asking those kind of question and that you should care when asking them.

- *What is the best way to ... ?*
- *Is there an optimal way to ... ?*

Those question sound completely different even though they ask for the same answer.

Finally even though that's not the topic right here, depending on how the question is written, I would probably call a close vote on *How can I prevent people from raging at eachother in a bad Game (League of Legends) ?* as off-topic since its about managing people within a team and not playing the game.

Comment: I personally don't think it's quite as clear to distinguish which are good and bad subjective, as some degree of knowledge in the game being asked about is required to make that judgement.  Might be worth a mention; but either way, +1.